# Merge objects in a single objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array with multiple objects as shown below

```
[{Name: "Product A", Qty: "5"}, {Name: "Product B", Qty: "2"}, {Name: "Product A", Qty: "6"}]
```

and was wondering how I can merge the object QTY field values in related product NAME to produce a new array like that shown below:

```
[{Name: "Product A", Qty: "11"}, {Name: "Product B", Qty: "2"}]
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've tried searching for a starting point but unfortunately couldn't find any to even start testing

Comment: You can simply iterate over the objects, check the name, if it exists in the new array, increment the new QTY by the value of it, else add it to the array.
I apologize I don't have time to write a code but hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to create one object and get values with `Object.values`.

```js
const data = [{Name: "Product A", Qty: "5"}, {Name: "Product B", Qty: "2"}, {Name: "Product A", Qty: "6"}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {Name, Qty}) => {
  if(!r[Name]) r[Name] = {Name, Qty: +Qty};
  else r[Name].Qty += +Qty;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```